# What was the actual narrative structure in Moebius by Kim Ki Duk?

Tags: plot-explanation, moebius

I've recently seen the last Kim Ki Duk movie [*Moebius*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2942522/) and I feel I didn't quite get the narrative structure.

I thought the whole film was pretty linear but the last scene, where you find out

> that the "monk" that was used to pray in front of the shop is the son,

made me wonder if I didn't overlook some aspect of the structure.

I'm not quite sure but I think that even the gun and the bullets in the drawer may play a role, even though I can't really explain why.

Is there a coherent explanation of the narrative structure?

Comment: Welcome to [movies.se]. While I haven't seen the movie, the question looks a bit broad. Do you want the whole movie explained? That's why I couldn't do much to improve the title. Maybe you could concretize the question and its title a bit?

Comment: @ChristianRau thanks for you suggestions. I thought it's pretty clear what I need but I'll see what I can do to improve the question.

Comment: I thought about this a little bit but I can't come up with something better. It really is just a "plot-explanation" question, I don't see how this may be too broad or else.

Comment: To answer your comment, no, I have not watched the movie. I read several synopses and attempted to answer based on your question about linearity and the last scene. Considering nobody else had attempted an answer in 7 months I thought it worth the try. Evidently not.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I was hoping for something a little bit more detailed.